# Cambiar las figuras dibujadas por una imagen propia

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero cambiar una figura dibujada en javascript por una propia, y no supe como hacerlo.

Las figuras se definen en el constructor con valores X e Y para que se muestren correctamente en el canvas, ademas de algunos eventos de la interfaz como las colisiones de los objetos, efectos de sonido, música de fondo y miscelanea de UI.

Para ordenar mis objetos que se van a usar utilizo la librería de Bootstrap.

La animacion de parpadeo tambien la quiero implementar en el this.message, necesito algo de guía en eso también por favor.

Agradecería mucho de antemano su ayuda y a la brevedad posible.

```js
const OWN_BULLET = 1;
const ENEMY_BULLET = 2;



class Bullet {
    constructor(x, y, type, speed, ctx) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.type = type;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.width = 20;
        this.height = 40;
    }

    



 


    moveUp() {
        this.y -= this.speed;
    }

    moveDown() {
        this.y += this.speed;
    }

    draw() {
        if (this.type == OWN_BULLET) {
            this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
        } else {
            this.ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        }

        this.ctx.fillRect(
            this.x + this.width * 2,
            this.y,
            this.width,
            this.height
        );
    }
}

class ShuttleGame {
    constructor() {
        let body = document.querySelector('body');
        this.canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
        this.message = 'Press  Enter  to  start!';

        this.shuttle = new Image();
        this.shuttle.src = 'shuttle.png';

        this.background = new Image();
        this.background.src = 'background.jpg';

        this.images = new Array();
        this.images.push(this.shuttle);
        this.images.push(this.background);

        this.speed = 30;
        this.playing = false;
        this.lastFiredBullet = null;

        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        this.shuttleX = canvas.width / 2;
        this.shuttleY = canvas.height - 150;
        
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        let moveLeftAction = this.moveLeft.bind(this);
        let moveRightAction = this.moveRight.bind(this);
        let fireBulletAction = this.fireBullet.bind(this);
        let startAction = this.start.bind(this);

        body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
                moveLeftAction();
            } else if (event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
                moveRightAction();
            } else if (event.key == 'Enter') {
                startAction();
                const audio = document.createElement("audio");
                audio.preload = "auto";
                audio.src = "newGame.mp3";
                audio.play();
                document.body.appendChild(audio);
            }
        });

        let numImages = 0;
        let updateCall = this.update.bind(this);

        for (let image of this.images) {
            image.onload = function() {
                if (++numImages >= 2) {
                    setInterval(updateCall, 10);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    start() {
        if (this.playing) {
            return;
        }

        this.shuttleX = this.canvas.width / 2;
        this.shuttleY = this.canvas.height - 150;

        let generateEnemyBulletsCall = this.generateEnemyBullets.bind(this);
        
        if (this.enemyBulletsInterval) {
            clearInterval(this.enemyBulletsInterval);
        }
        
        this.enemyBulletsInterval = setInterval(generateEnemyBulletsCall, 2000);

        let fireBulletCall = this.fireBullet.bind(this);
        
        if (this.ownBulletsInterval) {
            clearInterval(this.ownBulletsInterval);
        }
        
        this.ownBulletsInterval = setInterval(fireBulletCall, 500);

        this.ownBullets = new Array();
        this.enemyBullets = new Array();

        this.playing = true;
        this.points = 0;

        this.showPoints();
    }

    showPoints() {
        this.message = 'POINTS:  ' + this.points;
    }

    gameOver() {
        this.playing = false;
        this.message = 'GAME  OVER!!!';
    }

    update() {
        let ctx = this.ctx;

        var pattern = ctx.createPattern(this.background, 'repeat');
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

        if (this.playing) {
            this.checkCollisions();
            this.cleanFiredBullets(this.ownBullets);

            for (let ownBullet of this.ownBullets) {
                ownBullet.moveUp();
                ownBullet.draw();
            }

            for (let enemyBullet of this.enemyBullets) {
                enemyBullet.moveDown();
                enemyBullet.draw();
            }
        } else {
            if (this.ownBullets) {
                for (let ownBullet of this.ownBullets) {
                    ownBullet.draw();
                }
            }

            if (this.enemyBullets) {
                for (let enemyBullet of this.enemyBullets) {
                    enemyBullet.draw();
                }
            }
        }



        ctx.drawImage(this.shuttle, this.shuttleX, this.shuttleY);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.font = '30pt Arcade';
        ctx.fillText(this.message, 30, 40);
    }

    checkCollisions() {
        for (let enemyBullet of this.enemyBullets) {
            if ((Math.abs(this.shuttleX - enemyBullet.x) < 20 &&
                Math.abs(this.shuttleY - enemyBullet.y) < 20) || 
                (enemyBullet.y >= this.canvas.height - enemyBullet.height)) {
                
                    const audio = document.createElement("audio");
                    audio.preload = "auto";
                    audio.src = "game_over.wav";
                    audio.play();
                    document.body.appendChild(audio);
                    
                
                this.gameOver();
                return;
            }
        }

        for (let ownBullet of this.ownBullets) {
            let i = this.enemyBullets.length;

            while (i--) {
                let enemyBullet = this.enemyBullets[i];
                if (Math.abs(ownBullet.x - enemyBullet.x) < 20 &&
                    Math.abs(ownBullet.y - enemyBullet.y) < 20) {
                    this.points += 1;
                    this.enemyBullets.splice(i, 1);
                    
                    const audio = document.createElement("audio");
                    audio.preload = "auto";
                    audio.src = "Explosion.mp3";
                    audio.play();
                    document.body.appendChild(audio);
                    
                    this.showPoints();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cleanFiredBullets(bullets) {
        let i = bullets.length;

        while (i--) {
            let bullet = bullets[i];
            if (bullet.type == OWN_BULLET && bullet.y <= -bullet.height) {
                bullets.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    moveLeft() {
        if (this.playing) {
            this.shuttleX -= this.speed;
        }
    }

    moveRight() {
        if (this.playing) {
            this.shuttleX += this.speed;
        }
    }

    fireBullet() {
        if (!this.playing) {
            return;
        }

        this.lastFiredBullet = new Bullet(this.shuttleX, this.shuttleY, OWN_BULLET, 10, this.ctx);
        this.ownBullets.push(this.lastFiredBullet);
        const audio = document.createElement("audio");
        audio.preload = "auto";
        audio.src = "laserShoot.wav";
        audio.play();
        document.body.appendChild(audio);
    }

    generateEnemyBullets() {
        if (!this.playing) {
            return;
        }

        let enemyBullet = new Bullet((Math.random() * (this.canvas.width * 2 / 3) + this.canvas.width / 6) , 0, ENEMY_BULLET, 3, this.ctx);
        this.enemyBullets.push(enemyBullet);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    new ShuttleGame();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: Arcade;
                src: url(ARCADECLASSIC.TTF);
            }

            .parpadea {
  
                animation-name: parpadeo;
                animation-duration: 1s;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
                animation-iteration-count: infinite;

                -webkit-animation-name:parpadeo;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            }

            @-moz-keyframes parpadeo{  
                0% { opacity: 1.0; }
                50% { opacity: 0.0; }
                100% { opacity: 1.0; }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes parpadeo {  
                0% { opacity: 1.0; }
                50% { opacity: 0.0; }
                100% { opacity: 1.0; }
            }

            @keyframes parpadeo {  
                0% { opacity: 1.0; }
                50% { opacity: 0.0; }
                100% { opacity: 1.0; }
            }
        </style>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio autoplay="true" loop>
            <source src="Bg_music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>


       
        <canvas class="parpadea" id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```